# How do I get all ID of the server that has my bot? I need to get all invite links of the server that have my bot

Tags: server, discord, discord.js, invite

I want to get all the invite links of the guilds/servers that have my bot in, how should I do it?

`client.guilds.array().sort()` only output server names. How should I get the ID/invite links of the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the ID's of the servers that have your bot, just loop through the array and print `guild.id`. For example:

```
var serverArray = client.guilds.array();
for(i = 0; i < serverArray.length; i++) {
    print("Server ID: " + serverArray[i].id);
}
```

If you want to get an invite link to the server, then use `guild.fetchInvites()`. Example:

```
var serverArray = client.guilds.array();
for(i = 0; i < serverArray.length; i++) {

    serverArray[i].fetchInvites().then(invites => {
        invites.map(invite => {
            print("Invite link: " + invite.url);
        });
    });

}
```

Note that the above example will only work if there are actually invite links to the server. If there are no invite links, then you can create one using `GuildChannel.createInvite()`. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.6.4/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createInvite